# Filtering list of object inside list of objects

Tags: java

So i have a list of objects:

```
        List<GpbCodesAndVersions> lst = Arrays.asList(new GpbCodesAndVersions("code1", 1, Arrays.asList(new General(1), new General(2))),
            new GpbCodesAndVersions("code2", 2,  Arrays.asList(new General(1), new General(5))),
            new GpbCodesAndVersions("code3", 3,  Arrays.asList(new General(2), new General(3))),
            new GpbCodesAndVersions("code4", 4,  Arrays.asList(new General(2), new General(4))));
```

And i want to filter this list and get list which includes only General(1) fields:
`GpbCodesAndVersions(code=code1, version=1, content=[General(status=1)]), GpbCodesAndVersions(code=code2, version=2, content=[General(status=1)])`

My code is working, but maybe it possible to do it more beautiful ?
My code:

```
    List<GpbCodesAndVersions> versionOneGeneral = lst.stream().peek(x -> {
        List<General> generals = x.getContent().stream().filter(y -> y.getStatus().equals(1)).toList();
        x.setContent(generals);
    }).filter(z -> !z.getContent().isEmpty()).toList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `peek` is generally not recommended for such tasks, because it forces you to use side-effects to modify the list in-place.

It is better to use side-effect-free `map` to create a new version of the list (functional-style):

```
final List<GpbCodesAndVersions> list = Arrays.asList(
        new GpbCodesAndVersions("code1", 1, Arrays.asList(new General(1), new General(2))),
        new GpbCodesAndVersions("code2", 2,  Arrays.asList(new General(1), new General(5))),
        new GpbCodesAndVersions("code3", 3,  Arrays.asList(new General(2), new General(3))),
        new GpbCodesAndVersions("code4", 4,  Arrays.asList(new General(2), new General(4))));

final List<GpbCodesAndVersions> newList = list.stream()
    .map(x -> new GpbCodesAndVersions(
            x.getCode(),
            x.getId(),
            x.getContent().stream().filter(g -> g.getStatus() == 1).toList()))
    .filter(Predicate.not(x -> x.getContent().isEmpty()))
    .toList();
```

This will leave all GpbCodesAndVersions unmodified in the original list and creates a new list containing new GpbCodesAndVersions with a new list of generals. Both lists are now independent and modifications of one list will not affect the other list (which avoids unindented modifications).

Comment: 1. I think putting filters before other actions is better for performance 2. why create a new GpbCodesAndVersions instead of change its content?

Comment: 1. yes, might be true, but not as clear (and you still need to iterate the content twice) 2. because streaming data should generally not mutate the source data. If you want to modify the source data, you're usually better off using a for-loop.

Answer (score 1):

I think anyMatch can help, thanks for correcting me @knittl

Just a small thing, it will immediately apply the `map` function after `filter out` one item from list, means the process will be in below order(in this case, first two item can be processed after filter), means **it will iterate the list only once**

```
filter, map, filter, map, filter, filter, other actions
```

```
List<GpbCodesAndVersions> result1 = list.stream()
        .filter(x -> x.getContent().stream().anyMatch(y -> y.getStatus() == 1))
        .map(x -> {
            List<General> generals2 = x.getContent().stream().filter(g -> g.getStatus() == 1).toList();
            x.setContent(generals2);
            return x;
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());


System.out.println("result1 = " + result1);

result1 = [GpbCodesAndVersions(code=code1, v=1, content=[General(status=1)]), GpbCodesAndVersions(code=code2, v=2, content=[General(status=1)])]
```

Comment: From what I understood from the question, the "content" must also be transformed and all items with status!=1 removed

Comment: The updated code will only ever return a single general in the content. What if the original items contained more than one general with status 1?